# recursive SED in specific files

Tags: recursion, sed, design-patterns

I want to change each pattern "evictions" with "128" in all files started with "tor*". I use

```
find . -name "tor*" -exec sed "s/evictions/128/g" '{}' \;
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you accept answers to some of the other questions you asked?

Comment: done... Since I asked my questions with less than 15 reputations, I couldn't vote up for them. Thanks for remembering that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the -i flag, which edits files in place.

Do this:

`find . -name "tor*" -exec sed -i "s/evictions/128/g" '{}' \;`